# How to get a random element from a Set in Scala

Tags: scala, random, collections, set, scala-collections

For any given set, for instance,

```
val fruits = Set("apple", "grape", "pear", "banana")
```

how to get a random element from `fruits` ?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

convert into `Vector` and get random element from it

```
scala> val fruits = Set("apple", "grape", "pear", "banana")
fruits: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(apple, grape, pear, banana)

scala> import scala.util.Random
import scala.util.Random

scala> val rnd=new Random
rnd: scala.util.Random = scala.util.Random@31a9253

scala> fruits.toVector(rnd.nextInt(fruits.size))
res8: String = apple
```

Comment: Indexing is `O(n)` on List. Why not use `Array` or `Vector`?

Comment: Can't scala.util.Random.nextInt occasionally return negative numbers?

Comment: @TimBarrass `nextInt()` will return a negative number half of the time, but `nextInt(n: Int)`, which is used here, starts at 0 and ends at `n` (exclusive): https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Random.html#nextInt(n:Int):Int

Comment: Or convert to `IndexedSeq`, and code to interfaces.

Answer (score 22):

So, every answer posted before has complexity **O(n) in terms of space,** since they create a copy a whole collection in some way. Here is a solution without any additional copying (therefore it is "constant space"):

```
def random[T](s: Set[T]): T = {
  val n = util.Random.nextInt(s.size)
  s.iterator.drop(n).next
}
```

Comment: This is a better answer for the reason you put forward. It could be done in a one liner like this:  val s = Set(1,2,3); s.drop(random.nextInt(s.size).head

Comment: @justinhj: Nope, your solution is O(n) space again, since `drop` on `Set` causes a set with the remaining elements to be created. You *have* to use iterators, because they are non-strict.

Comment: Good solution. Its worth pointing out that if the set is empty `it.next` will throw.

Comment: @AntonyPerkov which makes sense because ... what does it mean to sample from an empty set?

Comment: This is still O(n) time, though.

Comment: Yes, I also look for a O(1) time and O(1) space version

Comment: You will have to create your own Set implementation for that. and the time will probably be O(log n) if you want to have other operations efficient.

Answer (score 3):

Drawing inspiration from the other answers to this question, I've come up with:

```
private def randomItem[T](items: Traversable[T]): Option[T] = {
  val i = Random.nextInt(items.size)
  items.view(i, i + 1).headOption
}
```

This doesn't copy anything, doesn't fail if the `Set` (or other type of `Traversable`) is empty, and it's clear at a glance what it does. If you're certain that the `Set` is not empty, you could use `.head` instead of `headOption`, returning a `T`.

Answer (score 2):

Solution1

Random way ( `import scala.util.Random` )

```
scala>  fruits.toList(Random.nextInt(fruits.size))
res0: java.lang.String = banana
```

Solution2

Math way (no imports)

```
scala> fruits.toList((math.random*fruits.size).toInt)
res1: String = banana
```

Comment: Chained List is not a good option to pick one element at random. Chose array or vector instead

Answer (score 2):

You can directly access an element of a Set with slice. I used this when I was working with a set that was changing in size, so converting it to a Vector every time seemed like overkill.

```
val roll = new Random ()

val n = roll nextInt (fruits size)
fruits slice (n, n + 1) last
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   import Scala.util.Random

   val fruits = Set("apple", "grape", "pear", "banana").toVector

   val sz =fruits.size

   val num = Random.nextInt(sz)

   fruits(num)
```

Comment: Yep, Set should be converted to container that supports accessing elements by sequential number. Vector is quicker than List.

Comment: @dividebyzero previously it was set

Answer (score 0):

Not converting the `Set` to an *ordered* collection but using `zipWithIndex` we can attribute an index to each item in the collection,

```
fruits.zipWithIndex
Set((apple,0), (grape,1), (pear,2), (banana,3))
```

Thus for `val rnd = util.Random.nextInt(fruits.size)`,

```
fruits.zipWithIndex.find( _._2 == rnd)
Option[(String, Int)] = Some((banana,3))
```

Given an empty set,

```
Set[String]().zipWithIndex.find( _._2 == 3)
Option[(String, Int)] = None
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind an `O(n)` solution:

```
import util.Random

// val fruits = Set("apple", "grape", "pear", "banana")
Random.shuffle(fruits).head
// "pear"
```