# How to efficiently pick a random element from an enumeration in scala?

Tags: scala, random, enums

I have an enum like this:

```
object Animals extends Enumeration {
  type Animals = Value
  val Monkey = Value("Monkey")
  val Lion = Value("Lion")
  val Dog = Value("Dog")
  val Cat = Value("Cat")
}
```

and I need to pick at random an element from this enumeration. How can i efficiently do this in scala?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Less than a minute with the [documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Enumeration) shows

`final def maxId: Int`

> The one higher than the highest integer amongst those used to identify values in this enumeration.

and

`final def apply(x: Int): Value`

> The value of this enumeration with given id x

So

```
Animals(scala.util.Random.nextInt(Animals.maxId))
//> res0: recursion.recursion.Animals.Value = Monkey
```

(assuming all values are used, and you didn't pass in an initial value to the constructor)

Or you could enumerate the values with `Animals.values` and then refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25053724/how-to-get-a-random-element-from-a-set-in-scala)